# How to edit symbols in row value

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have column **code** with rows 1231AC, 2163BC, 6142ED. Row values should be transformed by following mapping: 1->A, 2->B, 3->C, 4->D, 5->E, 6->F, 7->G, 8->H, 9->I, 0->J and added to new column **transformed_code**

```
val followingMapping = Map(1 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B', 3 -> 'C', 4 -> 'D',
              5 -> 'E', 6 -> 'F', 7 -> 'G', 8 -> 'H', 9 -> 'I', 0 -> 'J')
```

Probaly it should be done with `udf` and with something like that:

```
val transform = udf {row: Row =>
    //transform row value 
}
df.withColumn("transformed_code", transform(df.col("code")))
```

but I don't know how? So I'm trying to do this with following code:

```
val b = df.select("code").collect()
            val rowValue = b(0).getString(0)
            for(i <- 0 until rowValue.length - 1)
            {
              println(c.charAt(i))
              val currentCharacter = c.charAt(i)
              //transform with mapping

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this could be done via UDF. See the below solution is how I've come up with it.

### Solutions:

```
  import spark.implicits._
  val someDf = Seq(("1234AB"), ("2345BC")).toDF("col1")

  val followingMapping = Map(1 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B', 3 -> 'C', 4 -> 'D',
    5 -> 'E', 6 -> 'F', 7 -> 'G', 8 -> 'H', 9 -> 'I', 0 -> 'J')
  // Transforms string into another string based on the map
  def someUdf: (String => String) = {str => str.map(c => followingMapping.getOrElse(c.toInt - 48, c))}
  val myUdf = udf(someUdf)
  someDf.show

  someDf.withColumn("col2", myUdf($"col1")).show
```

The above code is self explainable. Below is how the output appears and they are in line with the `show` function as used above:

### Output:

```
scala>   someDf.show
+------+
|  col1|
+------+
|1234AB|
|2345BC|
+------+


scala>   someDf.withColumn("col2", myUdf($"col1")).show
+------+------+
|  col1|  col2|
+------+------+
|1234AB|ABCDAB|
|2345BC|BCDEBC|
+------+------+
```

Let me know if this helps!